# Unknown function 'length' at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/SQL/Statement.pm line 88

Tags: sql, perl, parsing

Here is a part of code:

```
use SQL::Statement;
my $qryParse = "select colA from tableB where length(colA)>0";
my $sqlParser = SQL::Parser->new();
$sqlParser->dialect('ANSI');
my $stmt = SQL::Statement->new($qryParse,$sqlParser);
```

The error says:

> Unknown function 'length' at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/SQL/Statement.pm line 88

.

How can I tell the parser that 'length' is a pl/sql function? Or maybe there are some pl/sql dialect files that also should be installed ?

Comment: What database is the query for? MySQL? pg?

Comment: Why are you using "SQL::Statement"?  Is this for input validation?

Comment: The task is to make a list of all tables/fields used in a big pack of queries, so SQL::Statement looks fine for it, but maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: Since you have requested an ANSI dialect, would the ANSI functions `CHARACTER_LENGTH` or `OCTET_LENGTH` suit your purpose better than the nonstandard function LENGTH?  Obviously that's not a general solution for nonstandard functions.

Comment: yes, changing function name is a one more way to solve this, but it also requires to check all available syntax, that is why i asked about dialect files. I have no idea what queries users will parse with my script and it should work for all of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options.  First is to [extend the syntax by issuing special SQL commands](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aStatement%3a%3aSyntax#Extending-SQL-syntax-using-SQL) to tell the parser about new functions.

```
my $extend_sql = "CREATE FUNCTION LENGTH";
my $sql = "select colA from tableB where length(colA)>0";

my $sqlParser = SQL::Parser->new();
$sqlParser->dialect('ANSI');

my $query = join ", ", $extend_sql, $sql;
my $stmt = SQL::Statement->new($query, $sqlParser);
```

This doesn't scale very well, so you'll be wanting to subclass with your extensions.  Unfortunately [the documentation for subclassing SQL::Parser](https://metacpan.org/module/REHSACK/SQL-Statement-1.405/lib/SQL/Parser.pm#Subclassing-SQL%3a%3aParser) doesn't shed much light on this.

Finally, you can write a SQL::Dialects::Oracle file using [SQL::Dialects::Role](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aDialects%3a%3aRole) or by subclassing [SQL::Dialects::ANSI](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aDialects%3a%3aANSI) and then use `$sqlParser->dialect('Oracle')`.  Unfortunately the critical `get_config` method which you'd be subclassing just returns a big string, so adding to it will be unwieldy.  Fortunately you can use `get_config_as_hash` to do that for you.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to specify a function. :(

Since I had so much trouble puzzling this out, I [reported it as a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=86214).  I also [reported a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=86213) which means `$sqlParser->dialect($dialect)` does nothing, you have to write `my $sqlParser = SQL::Parser->new($dialect)`.

Comment: @Kate Updated with some information about writing a dialects file, but I can't provide a complete answer.